# Monitoring resource loading time for a mobile site

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, mobile-website, resource-monitor

I'm developing a mobile site. Right now it takes a long time to load. Can anyone suggest a good tool for determining where the page load is getting jammed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery Mobile mobile web site (and only a jQM site) you can use a simple benchmark script specially designed for jQuery Mobile sites.

Take a look at my other article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600, there's a chapter at the bottom about page benchmarking.